# BigQuery import for column type TIMESTAMP converts datetime offset/timezone, but column type DATETIME fails with `Invalid datetime string`

Tags: python, datetime, google-bigquery, datetimeoffset

When using TIMESTAMP column type, BigQuery seems to take a format like

```
2021-07-14 00:02:30.917983+02:00
```

*(generated using datime.isoformat(sep = ' ') ecause TIMESTAMP doesn't support iso-format with T separator)*

but then converts it to UTC:

```
2021-07-14 00:04:30.917983 UTC
```

Since I want the local time I tried to create a new column with DATETIME type

**JSON I'm trying to import:**

```
"load_time_local": "2021-07-15 02:01:02.478638+02:00",
"load_time_local2": "2021-07-15 02:01:02.478638+02:00"
```

**Accompanying schema:**

```
{
    "name": "load_time_local",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP",
    "mode": "REQUIRED"
},
{
    "name": "load_time_local2",
    "type": "DATETIME",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
},
```

This leads to an error:

```
Invalid datetime string "2021-07-15 02:01:02.478638+02:00" Field: load_time_local2;
```

Does Big Query support Timezones or Datetime offsets? Or do i have to strip the offset and import as a local time?

If I want to capture timezone information I'd need two columns with either utc + local time or local time + offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Query does not support timezone information on dates... BUT Timestamp is always expected to be UTC, thats why it accepts offsets on import, but then just converts it back to UTC.

In order to get the local time into a DATETIME field, the timezone offset information has to be removed.

With python this works:

```
berlin = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
datetime.now(berlin).replace(tzinfo=None).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not very clear about this.

When you import datetime data into Big Query:

1. You cannot specify the timezone
2. Bigquery wants `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format (like ISODate, but with a space instead of a `T`character).
3. All datetimes must be in UTC for insert.

When you query from big query you *can* use timezones (in fact, you should):

```sql
select * from `myproject.mydateset.csvimport`
where timestamp_field_0 > '2020-01-01T10:00:00+2'
```

If you need the original timezone when this date was recorded (because a human needs to see it), the easiest way to do it is to record the timezone in the same table. Fortunately Bigquery is a columnar DB and that timezone information will need little storage since it'll be compressed by bigquery.

Be careful to store the correct timezone in BigQuery!
Do not store geographical timezones like 'Europe/Madrid' because BigQuery will use the current offset from UTC when the query is run to calculate the localtime.
Store proper timezones like CET, CEST, EST, EDT, etc.

This way you can convert it during the query easily:

```sql
select STRING(utc_timestamp, timezone) from table
```

Comment: In most cases I just want to see query results in local time from the actual time they were captured, not the current daylight saving time... but then that is not possible?

Comment: That's tricky since the date for DST changes every year :-( - unless you store the original timezone in another column in the same table (BQ will compress that data and will take very little space - maybe 2-4 bits per record) - To convert the timestamp to another timezone just call ```STRING( your_datetime_column, "CET" ) ``` (this example shows the datetime in the Central European timezone.